# UISwipeGestureRecognizer on one half of the view

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a problem with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and can't find the solution for it.

I want to use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` only on one half of the view. But I also want to use buttons on my view.

Here is what I did.

I have a `UIView` named `firstView` that is is 768 x 1024 px with buttons on it.

Now I want to add a `UIView` or `UIImageView` on top of `firstView` named `secondView` that is 768 x 512 px.

The swipe will work but my buttons beneath `secondView` (buttons are on `firstView`) won't work.

What function did I miss to make both views respond?
Or is there an even better method than I described above?

My swipe code:

```
UIImageView *secondView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                              CGRectMake(0,0,768,512)] autorelease];
//UIView *secondView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768,512)] autorelease];

secondView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;    

[firstView addSubview:secondView];

oneFingerSwipeLeft = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                         action:@selector(swipeRecognition:)] autorelease];
[oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[secondView addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for myself. I put the screen in 4 views. Now i can give each view its own gesture recognition.

```
    // set CGRect for downLeftView
    downLeftView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,512,384,512)] autorelease];

    // set CGRect for downRightView
    downRightView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(384,512,384,512)] autorelease];

    // set CGRect for upRightView
    upRightView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,384,512)] autorelease];

    // set CGRect for upLeftView
    upLeftView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(384,0,384,512)] autorelease];
```